# Running both default and production profile during release

Tags: maven

My build is as follows:

The first is the normal build (mvn clean install)
The other is a profile activated by property (mvn clean install -Dbuild=prod)

The first deploys to Nexus.
The second profile deploys to a production server.

How can I run both builds during the Maven release cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the nexus-deploy out to a different profile and use multiple target execution:

Create a different profile to cater for the normal build and execute both targets on the build server like so:

```
mvn clean install -Dbuild=prod -Pdeploy
```

Comment: tried adding 2 profiles but only the second profile is getting called:

mvn clean deploy -P first-deploy,second-deploy

Answer (score 0):

mabe [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) can to do this. look Appfuse for example, it use `mvn jetty:run-war` to deploy in jetty and `mvn cargo:start` start to deploy to tomcat